# Where Zope 2 encodes/decode request.form.items

Tags: encoding, plone, zope

Plone 3.3.x

On one server, self.request.post.values() are unicode (correct).
On another server, they are bytestrings.

What is going on?

Where in the depth of Zope monster this is decided? Why they are different? Why I am loosing all hair before I have turned 30?

Comment: z3c.form. I suspect Five is somehow involved.

Comment: also z3c.form requires Unicode. Otherwise it does not work. For some reason, this one instance on one server, started to spit out bytestrings. You'll get "Object not valid" or similar error message on any field when you try to submit a form. AT forms work, still.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default Zope 2 leaves the request values encoded. But some form libraries (formlib, z3c.form) were written for Zope 3 and want to deal with Unicode, so there is a helper in Five (processInputs) which they call to decode the request before doing anything else

plone.z3cform does this by monkey-patching the base form class's update method to call processInputs. It sounds like that is not getting called in your case, for some reason.

Comment: Ok. Looks like monkey-patching is failing:

2011-03-24 10:17:13 ERROR collective.monkeypatcher Could not patch because version not recognized. Wanted: [2, 13, 9], Installed: []
2011-03-24 10:17:13 INFO collective.monkeypatcher Preconditions for patching scope <class 'z3c.form.form.BaseForm'> not met (Zope2-=2.13.999)!
2011-03-24 10:17:13 ERROR collective.monkeypatcher Could not patch because version not recognized. Wanted: [2, 13, 9], Installed: []
2011-03-24 10:17:13 INFO colle

Comment: I also hit this one, only there is no monkey-patching going on at all. Can we solve this one properly?